# EF is Database driven development?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-driven

Is 'Database Driven Development in windows' same as Application development uses Entity Framework. or is this (DB Driven Dev) has to use different framework or design?

Please comment. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what DDD is, but EF is a type safe way to access your database. It has nothing to do with your development methods.

Comment: EF supports a few workflows: Code First (including Code First to an existing database), Model First and Database First. You can reverse engineer a database with the EF Designer which will create an EF model in form of an edmx file that can be then used at runtime. To do that create a new project, add a new item to the project and select "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" and in the wizard select "Create from Database". Once the wizard is complete entities will be created and you will be able to access your data using EF.

Answer (score 2):

Database Driven Design is basically where you have the database design done first, then you program an application based upon the database. [Database driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-driven_programming)

Entity Framework is a Object Relational Mapping tool. Using EF, you can do a "code-first" database design where EF will create your database for you, but that's still not database driven design.

Comment: This is not true. EF supports a few workflows starting from CodeFirst trhough Code First to an existing database, Model First and finally Database First (Model First and Database First are workflows that require using the EF designer).